# what are the possible ways to force mathematica to show -1+a as a-1

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am just getting started with pattern in mathematica. I want to know what the different ways to force mma to show `-1+a` as `a-1`. Many thanks!

Comment: @belisarius: do you have some input to this thread? many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is probably `-1 + a // TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 5):

One due to Jean-Marc Gulliet ([MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Oct/msg00016.html))

(You may also be interested in the reply of Jens-Peer Kuska to this [post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Oct/msg00019.html))

```
PolynomialForm[-1 + a, TraditionalOrder -> True]
```

Out[34]= a-1

(`PolynomialForm` is undocumented, as far as I know.  I am using Mma 7.)

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use a hack like this

```
$PrePrint = (# /. -1 + expr__ :> Interpretation[Row[{expr, -1}], expr - 1]) &
```

But (as WReach suggests) it might be best to use the default Mathematica ordering of expressions and use `TraditionalForm` when you want it to look more like what a human would write.